# I was try run bellow code. but error getting mysql work bench. Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if exists sentinel_SP;

create procedure sentinel_SP(IN  __jobRefNo VARCHAR(70),IN  __bondSlNo VARCHAR(3),IN  __bondNo VARCHAR(20),IN  __bondCode VARCHAR(50),IN __bondPort VARCHAR(100))
    begin
        declare noOfTimes int;
        select count(jobRefNo) into noOfTimes from sntl_bond_details_import where jobRefNo=__jobRefNo;
        select noOfTimes;
        IF noOfTimes=0 THEN 
            INSERT INTO sntl_bond_details_import (jobRefNo,bondSlNo,bondNo,bondCode,bondPort) VALUES __jobRefNo,__bondSlNo,__bondNo,__bondCode,__bondPort;
        ELSE
            UPDATE sntl_bond_details_import SET jobRefNo=__jobRefNo,bondSlNo=__bondSlNo,bondNo=__bondNo,bondCode=__bondCode,bondPort=__bondPort;
        END IF;        
    end; $$
```

Comment: Null safe equal in mysql is <=> (not ==) AND value clause values start with ( and end with ) And please don't edit code to make it unreadable see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Reassign delimiter AFTER dropping the procedure.